# Preg-replace only H1 image

Tags: php, html, css, regex, preg-replace

How can I replace only the H1 background image? This is my CSS:

```
h1 a {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
background: url('http://mywebsite.com/img/old-logo.png') no-repeat;
}
```

This is my preg_replace code:

```
$document = preg_replace('/background[-image]*:[\s]*url\(\'?([^\'\)]+)\'?\)/', "background: url('http://mywebsite.com/img/new-logo.png')", $document);
```

But now it replaces all background images.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: wouldn't be more logical do a simple replace of "old-logo" with "new-logo", no matter on which css rule is inserted?

Comment: Why not simply: `str_replace("old-logo.png", "new-logo.png", $cssstr);` OR `str_replace("/img/old-logo.png", "/img/new-logo.png", $cssstr);`

Comment: The directory of the logo is constantly changing so that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$document = preg_replace(
    '/((?:^|\s|,)h1(?:[^}]+))background[-image]*:[\s]*url\(\'?([^\'\)]+)\'?\)/m',
    "$1background: url('http://mywebsite.com/img/new-logo.png')",
    $document
);
```

Comment: @TonHoekstra I'm glad it helps - and I'll be glad too if you accept the answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: I've only 1 problem the pattern also changes the background image of div#footer and other divs. How to fix that?

Comment: Do those rules have selectors such as div#footer { ... } or do the selectors contain h1 too?

Comment: They contain not H1, here is a example:
div#footer{background: url('URLHERE') repeat-y; height:180px; width:790px; color: #333}

Comment: @TonHoekstra I'm testing and the regex seems to work fine for me. Do you think we could see your style sheet?

Comment: It's fixed. I saw the cached version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you've used h1 in your webpage use id="h1" and declare your css like this;

```
#h1 a {margin: 0 auto;display: block;background: url('http://mywebsite.com/img/old-logo.png') no-repeat;}
```

Then call this javascript code to replace h1 background. Please #h1 is different from h1.

```
document.getElementById("h1").style.backgroundImage = url("img/new-logo.png");
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("h1").style.backgroundImage.src = "img/new-logo.png";<br>
```

Well, if none work then create another css id tag call it

```
#h2 a {margin: 0 auto;display: block;background: url('http://mywebsite.com/img/new-logo.png') no-repeat;}
```

Then, switch from h1 to h2 with javascript code below;

```
document.getElementById("h1").id = "h2";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this pattern:

```
'/h1.*\{.*background[-image]*:[\s]*url\(\'?([^\'\)]+)\'?\).*\}/m'
```